# How can I resolve this error about TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I try to resolve this error but I don't have idea what is the way to resolve it. Below I attach my code:[image]

And this is the error:

[image]

Comment: As a note, in the future please copy and paste your code/error and wrap it in triple backticks `\`\`\`` so it is easier for others to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be defining your `open` property incorrectly. You'll also need to define an interface that declares your properties. Try changing your `transform` line to something like this:

```
transform: ${props => props.open ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(100%)'};
```

And add an interface to be used like this:

```
interface UlProps {
   open: boolean;
}

const Ul = styled.ul<UlProps>`
   ...
`
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using the regular `styled components` library in a typescript file which does not ship with ts support.

You gotta install the typescript version using command `npm i --save-dev @types/styled-components`.

Then you could define props like

```
const UI = styled.ul<{open: boolean}>`
    \\your regular style here
`;
```

and use it like

```js
<UI open={open}>
{/*children here*/}
</UI>
```

References : [This blog](https://blog.agney.dev/styled-components-&-typescript/)